# overriding django default form rendering in templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

Model:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
  description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
```

Forms:

```
class SearchTypeForm(forms.Form):
  subject = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Subject.objects.all())
```

Views:

```
...
context['search_type_form'] = SearchTypeForm()
...
```

Template:

```
{{search_type_form.subject}}
```

In actual templates the search type form is rendered as:

```
<select id="id_subject" name="subject">
<option selected="selected" value="">---------</option>
<option value="1">subject 1</option>
<option value="2">subject 2</option>
...
</select>
```

In the value field(of above dropdown list) is the id of the corresponding subject, How it be changed to some other field, like is we want to make it the **slug field of Subject model**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override it by specifiing "to_field_name" keyword argument like this:

```
from django import forms

from some.models import Something

class SomeForm(forms.Form):
something = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Something.objects.all(), 
                                   to_field_name="slug")
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on `__unicode__` method of the model. Make it return `slug`:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
  description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.slug
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. But it wasn't working for me, It was giving id even if we had given the `__unicode__`

Comment: @saurabh Oh, I misread you question. You want to change the value. It's always primary key of the model. Define primary key explicitly and it will be used as value. Why do you need to change it anyway?

Comment: Actually in an ajax call I needed that value, when we use jQuery val it gives that value only. Anyways I got your point.. Thanks a lot..